# Postfix multiple instance only default work

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record, multiple-instances

Let me explain what I'm doing and what I want to reach from this postfix multiple instances

> I have domain for example "example1.com" and "mail.example1.com" for mail server and has proper DNS MX records and everything is fine, Now I have another domain "example2.com" and "mail.example2.com" for mail server, Each time I send mail from server the mail went to clients SPAM folder and the smtp.mailfrom shows "mail.example1.com"& IP: 1.1.1.1 (for example) at the end I found the newer domain in websites mails blacklist databases, So I searched for a solution but at the end it appears that I must use 2 myhostname by create additional postfix instance to accomplish this and for complete isolation.

I created another instance called "postfix-secondary" via this command:

```
postmulti -e init
```

Then created it by this command:

```
postmulti -I postfix-secondary -e create
```

After that mad it run via this:

```
postmulti -i postfix-secondary -p start
```

The problem now is the emails still forced to go through "mail.example1.com" even with disabled the default mail server and I see it kept gathered in the default queue

I will list the configs now
(example1.com) /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/mail_blacklist
myhostname = mail.example1.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.example1.com, example1.com, localhost.example1.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 1.1.1.1
inet_protocols = ipv4

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        permit

smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname


default_process_limit = 100
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 30
queue_minfree = 20971520
header_size_limit = 51200
message_size_limit = 10485760
smtpd_recipient_limit = 100
disable_vrfy_command= yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
```

(example1.com) /etc/postfix/master.cf (default)

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

(example2.com) /etc/postfix-secondary/main.cf

```
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

readme_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
#master_service_disable = inet
authorized_submit_users = 
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-secondary
multi_instance_name = postfix-secondary

myhostname = mail.example2.com
inet_interfaces = 2.2.2.2
multi_instance_enable = yes
mydestination = mail.example2.com, example2.com, localhost.example2.com, localhost



smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/mail_blacklist
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
relayhost = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
#smtp_bind_address = 0.0.0.0


smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        permit

smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
        reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname


default_process_limit = 100
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 30
queue_minfree = 20971520
header_size_limit = 51200
message_size_limit = 10485760
smtpd_recipient_limit = 100
disable_vrfy_command= yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20



append_dot_mydomain = no


smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

(example2.com) /etc/postfix-secondary/master.cf (default)

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

The DNS records for (example1.com) is fine and same as DNS for (example2.com) execpt different domain & IP:

```
example2.com.   IN  MX  10 mail.example2.com.
mail.example2.com.          IN      A  2.2.2.2
example2.      IN TXT     "v=spf1 mx ip4:2.2.2.2/32 ~all"
_dmarc.example2.com.    IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; pct=100; p=none; adkim=r; aspf=r"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal to have a mail server e.g. `mail.example.com` as an outgoing MTA for a different domain e.g. `example.net`. As a matter of facts this is the usual way; service providers hosting hundreads of domains doesn't have a new Postfix instance for every single domain.

Forget what you are doing and deploy [*Sender Policy Framework* (SPF)](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction), instead. Let the receiving MTAs know that `mail.example.com` is allowed to send mail for `example.net`, or even better, refer to the server with its IP address i.e. use the [`ip4` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4).

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I really need to hide the first domain (example1.com) from the mails info of (example2.com) mails. I need complete isolation. So if anyone try to know the sender he only gets (mail.example2.com)

Thanks

Comment: I tried your method when I gave up on the idea of my last comment here, But unfortunately My mails still go to SPAM folder.

Comment: See the full headers of the message flagged as spam. There should be hints of the reason.

Comment: Can you check the message source, it can't fit here so I posted it in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0ziZ07Kj

Edit:
1.1.1.1 for main mail server -which is working fine- mail.example1.com

In the 2nd domain (example2.com) DNS records:
TXT @ v=spf1 mx ip4:1.1.1.1/32 -all

TXT _dmarc   v=DMARC1; p=none

A  mail  1.1.1.1

MX example2  mail.example1.com

Comment: According to this the SPF record hasn't yet been used, `none`. Probably there's still DNS cache that hasn't expired.

Comment: Edit:
1.1.1.1 for main mail server -which is working fine- mail.example1.com

In the 2nd domain (example2.com) DNS records:
TXT @  v=spf1 mx ip4:1.1.1.1/32 -all
#####
TXT _dmarc   v=DMARC1; p=none
#####
A  mail  1.1.1.1
#####
MX example2  mail.example1.com

remove #